# Divide list with the single number in tcl NS-2

Tags: amazon-s3, tcl, ns2, knox-amazon-s3-client

i want to divide the whole list with one number.Lets say i take a variable $Content and i want to divide the following list with the 300 nodes.
so i take the command $Content/300

1. $Content= {1 2 3 4 5}{ 2 3 4 5 6} { 4 5 6 7 8 9}{3 4  6 8 9 0}

As a result output comes out {1 2 3 4 5}{ 2 3 4 5 6} { 4 5 6 7 8 9}{3 4  6 8 9 0}/300 with the parenthesis missing and invalid arguments.

Please tell me how we divide all list with the single number(300 nodes) because in curly brackets each number comes  as an output of some arguments

Comment: What output do you expect from the operation you are trying to perform?

Comment: i want to generate some output from this list.Actually $Content contains some arguments ($delay, $range , $priority)and this arguments generate some value in the form of list.And then we divide with the total number of nodes . so on the basis of this output i will decide either i will choose this best forwarder or not..

Comment: Sorry, your explanation of what you are trying to achieve is not clear.  As I said, please give a **literal** example of the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Tcl is a very whitespace-sensitive language, so you need a space between the close and open braces in your $Content declaration.

You can iterate over $Content, and for each sublist, iterate over the elements and divide by 300, collecting the results:

```
set Content {{1 2 3 4 5} { 2 3 4 5 6} { 4 5 6 7 8 9} {3 4  6 8 9 0}}
# note the spaces ......^............^..............^
set divisor 300
set newContent [list]
foreach sublist $Content {
    set newSublist [list]
    foreach elem $sublist {
        lappend newSublist [expr {$elem * 1.0 / $divisor}]
    }
    lappend newContent $newSublist
}
puts $newContent
```

Output is

```
{0.0033333333333333335 0.006666666666666667 0.01 0.013333333333333334 0.016666666666666666} {0.006666666666666667 0.01 0.013333333333333334 0.016666666666666666 0.02} {0.013333333333333334 0.016666666666666666 0.02 0.023333333333333334 0.02666666666666667 0.03} {0.01 0.013333333333333334 0.02 0.02666666666666667 0.03 0.0}
```

If your Tcl version is 8.6 you can use the `lmap` command to shorten up the code:

```
set newContent [lmap sublist $Content {
    lmap elem $sublist {expr {$elem * 1.0 / $divisor}}
}]
```

Note that I multiply by `1.0` in order to use float division and not integer division.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your response @Glenn Jackman. Actually $content contains some arguments ($delay $range $priority $i) on the basis of these arguments $content generate automatically 4-tuples {1 2 3 4}{5 6 7 8} list , we divide this list with the number of nodes in order to take some decision, either  to choose the best forwarder or not .
set no_cs [llength expr {[$Content]/$num_nodes}]
$Content/$num_nodes .output gives me the error ( invalid argument and it should be length list .).Now you tell me the possible solution or hint in order to view the above code

Comment: Glenn Jackmen i run your code but unfortunately ""it gave me error
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "*"
    while executing
"expr {$elem * 1.0 / $divisor}"
    ("foreach" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"foreach elem $sublist {
        lappend newSublist [expr {$elem * 1.0 / $divisor}]
    }""""

now please tell me what i do?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you mean by "divide a list by 300"? Is my assumption correct that you want to divide every number in the list by 300?

Comment: When you got that error, what *exactly* was the value of $content?

Comment: yes, Glenn Jackman i want to divide every number in the list by 300..  and got some value.

Comment: thank you. output shows the invalid command name "expr{name size priort delay range {1 40 2 100 137}........{498 386 3 50 15} {499 15 3 50 15} {500 386 3 50 15}/300}" while executing "expr{$Content/$num_nodes}"invoked from within"set no_cs [expr{$Content $num_nodes}]".Actually Content = {1 40 2 100 137} {2 7 3 50 15}.......{499 15 3 50 15} {500 386 3 50 15} contains this list.Set num_nodes = 300 .And I try all these lists /with a number of nodes= 300, by using  this command ,set no_cs [expr{$Content/$num_nodes}].kindly, sir now tell me what i do?

Comment: I mentioned the whitespace: You **must** separate the command (`expr`) from the arguments with whitespace. See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm for the very few syntax rules of Tcl

Comment: Also, `$Command` is a **list**. You cannot divide a **list of values** by 300. I showed you how to break up the list into sublists into elements.

Comment: sir  @Glenn Jackman, i run your above code as it is, but the output shows the error on this line 
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "*"
    while executing
"expr {$elem * 1.0 / $divisor}"
 invoked from within
"foreach elem $sublist {
        lappend newSublist [expr {$elem * 1.0 / $numbernodes}]
    }"

Comment: What is the value of $elem when that happens? What is the contents of $Content? Are any of the elements non-numbers?

Comment: According to your code, element contain $sublist and $sublist contain $content and $content contain elements list {1 40 2 100 137}......{ 498 386 3 50 15}{499 15 3 50 15}{500 386 3 50 15} and elements list contains no character or string.I just run your code 
set numbernodes 300
set newContents [list]
puts ="$Content"
foreach sublist $Content {
   set newSublist [list]
  foreach elem $sublist {
        lappend newSublist [expr {$elem * 1.0 / $numbernodes}]
    }
    lappend newContents $newSublist
}
puts $newContents